# Grunt dynamic build for a lot of CSS with wildcard

Tags: dynamic, gruntjs, less

I'm currenty using Grunt and Less for minifing files and I want use this on my code only - there are many 3rd party files. Is possible use wildcard of some filter function? My Drupal modules have prefix 'snype'.

```
   less: {
        development: {
            files: [
                {
                    expand: true,     
                    cwd: '<%= path.source %>snype*',      
                    src: ['**/*.less'], 
                    dest: '<%= path.destination %>',   
                    ext: '.css',   
                    extDot: 'first'   
                },
            ],  
        },  
    },
```

But this doesn't work... If I remove snype* from cwd, so it works.

Answer (score 1):

In the example you have set the root folder to *<%= path.source %>snype* which may not be correct.

Instead you should specify your patterns in the src, like:

```
src: ['**/snype*.less']
```

but you can also exclude 3rd party folders by prefixing them with **!**:

```
// All .js files in my_folder; except those in drupal folder, etc
{src: ['my_folder/*.js', '!drupal/*.js'....]}
```

Take a look at the **Globbing patterns** section [here](http://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks).

If you have a complex folder structure and many excludes you may consider using a globbing function like

```
var createFolderGlobs = function(fileTypePatterns) {
    fileTypePatterns = Array.isArray(fileTypePatterns) ? fileTypePatterns : [fileTypePatterns];
    var ignore = ['node_modules', 'bower_components', 'dist', 'temp']; //you put here folders to ignore

    var fs = require('fs');
    var ret = fs.readdirSync(process.cwd())
    .map(function(file) {
        if (ignore.indexOf(file) !== -1 ||
            file.indexOf('.') === 0 ||
            !fs.lstatSync(file).isDirectory()) {
            //console.log("RB JSHINT DEBUG: ignoring file:" + file);
            return null;
        } else {
            return fileTypePatterns.map(function(pattern) {
                return file + '/**/' + pattern;
            });
        }
    })
    .filter(function(patterns) {
        return patterns;
    })
    .concat(fileTypePatterns);
return ret;
```

};

that you can put directly in the *files* option:

```
    less: {                
            files: [createFolderGlobs(['*.less'])],
            tasks: ['less:dev'], //whatever else you may need 
        },
```

considering that exclusion patterns slows down Grunt significantly.

I came over this function by using cg-angular generator from **cgross**, you can find it [here](https://github.com/cgross/generator-cg-angular/blob/master/app/templates/skeleton/Gruntfile.js). Read the comments at the top for a more detailed explanation.

Comment: Why can't use `src: ['<%= path.source %>**/snype*.less']`? I've defined `path: {
    destination: 'assets/',
    source: 'sites/all/modules/'
}` 

Of course, I tried use globbing patterns, but not works. All my modules has prefix `snype`, but Drupal modules aren't any prefix, so I must use some more complex function for globbing files and folders.

Your function `createFolderGlobs` returns this error: `Warning: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'src' in Ciprian/**/*.less Use --force to continue`